# Incompatible pointer type error during calling a function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I want to create a program that will implement a Line Editor which will take lines as input and prints them

I'm using cursors to manipulate Singly Linked Lists, but I'm getting error in displayFromCursor, displayAll, moveCursor functions due to incompatible Pointer type, where did I went wrong?
Please help, I'm stuck here at this point

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct node
{
    char line[300];
    struct node *link;
}NODE;

typedef struct cursor
{
    NODE *prev;
    NODE *next;
}CURSOR;

typedef struct list
{
    NODE *link;
    int count;
}LIST;

void takeCommand(CURSOR **pCursor,LIST **pList);
void insertLine(CURSOR **pCursor,LIST**);
void deleteLine(CURSOR **pCursor,LIST **pList);
void moveCursor(CURSOR **pCursor,LIST **pList);
void displayFromCursor(CURSOR **pCursor);
void displayAll(LIST **pList);

void main(void)
{
    LIST *pList;
    pList->count = 0;
    pList->link = NULL;

    CURSOR *pCursor;
    pCursor->prev = NULL;
    pCursor->next = NULL;

    takeCommand(&pCursor,&pList);
    printf("BYE\n");
    return;
}

void takeCommand(CURSOR **pCursor,LIST **pList)
{
    char c;
    printf(">");
    c=getchar();
    switch(c)
    {
    case 'I': insertLine(pCursor,pList);
        case 'D': deleteLine(pCursor,pList);
            case 'M': moveCursor(pCursor,pList);
                case 'L': displayFromCursor(pCursor);
                    case 'A': displayAll(pList);
                        case 'X':return;
                        default : printf("Enter correct value again");
    }
    takeCommand(pCursor,pList);
}

void insertLine(CURSOR **pCursor,LIST **pList)
{
    char newLine[300];
    bool x=true;
    do
    {
        if(strcmp(newLine,"//"))
        {
            x=false;
        }
        else
        {
            scanf("%s",newLine);
            NODE *pNew;
            pNew = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
            strcpy(pNew->line,newLine);
            pNew->link = (*pCursor)->next;
            (*pCursor)->prev = pNew;
            ((*pList)->count)++;
        }
    }while(true);
    return;
}

void deleteLine(CURSOR **pCursor,LIST **pList)
{
    NODE *temp;
    temp->link = (*pCursor)->next;
    (*pCursor)->next = ((*pCursor)->next)->link;
    free(temp);
    ((*pList)->count)--;
    return;
}

void displayFromCursor(CURSOR **pCursor)
{
    if((*pCursor)->next !=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",(*pCursor)->next->line);
        displayFromCursor( ((*pCursor)->next) );
    }
    return;
}

void displayAll(LIST **pList)
{
    if((*pList)->link !=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",(*pList)->link->line);
        displayFromCursor( ((*pList)->link) );
    }
    return;
}

void moveCursor(CURSOR **pCursor,LIST **pList)
{
    int countNew=(*pList)->count;
    int temp,i;
    printf("Enter the number to move cursor\n");
    scanf("%d",&temp);
    countNew-=temp;
    while((*pCursor)->next !=NULL)
    {
        (*pCursor) = (*pCursor)->next;
        countNew--;
    }
    (*pCursor)->next = (*pList)->link;
    (*pCursor)->prev = NULL;
    for(i=0;i<countNew;i++)
    {
        (*pCursor)->prev = (*pCursor)->next;
        (*pCursor)->next = (*pCursor)->next->link;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Note that you are having a fall through situation in Switch case statements. You program compiled [fine](http://ideone.com/UoXabC) but got a run-time error which you need to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in Line

`displayFromCursor( ((*pCursor)->next) );`

where function displayFromCursor is expecting `struct CURSOR **` as an argument but actually argument is of type `struct NODE *`.Similarly in function `displayAll`.You simply need to pass `pCursor` as argument.